# Adding a menu item in the admin bar

Tags: wp-admin, admin-menu, admin-bar, menu-order

I would like to add a new menu item in the admin bar. So far, I have done the following:

```
function add_book_menu_item ($wp_admin_bar) {

    $args = array (
            'id'        => 'book',
            'title'     => 'Book',
            'href'      => 'http://example.com/',
            'parent'    => 'new-content'
    );

    $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );
}

add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'add_book_menu_item');
```

This is creating the `Book` menu item underneath the `+ New` menu (in the admin toolbar). However, the `Book` item comes in first (it is before the `Post` menu item). I would like it to appear between the `Media` and `Page` items.

The following image shows what I would like to do.

[image]

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

every menu have an number . lower the number priority.

```
 add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_sidebar_toggle', 0 );
            add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_wp_menu', 10 );
            add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_my_sites_menu', 20 );
            add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_site_menu', 30 );
```

more clear idea you can check the link below

http://natko.com/custom-menu-item-position-in-wordpress-admin-bar-toolbar/

Comment: Thanks. I tried this already. Does not work for what I am doing. This would work for the *root* menu items. For me, everything is under the `New` node (which is a *root* node). Therefore, priorities would not work. By the way, if I add priority of **70**, then `Book` appears on top. If I make the priority **71**, it is at the bottom of the list (beneath `User`).

Comment: http://natko.com/custom-menu-item-position-in-wordpress-admin-bar-toolbar/ Has a list of the items numbers for arranging order.

Comment: @Sam - Yes, but the *root* node is a custom node (namely, it is **Custom Node**), and his solution would not work on extending a node that is already created (i.e., the **New** node that I like to extend).

Comment: can you set 20 or 30 ?

Comment: @Akankhaahmed - Yes, I did, anything below **70** shows the item at the top.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using Jquery.

The new menu drop down --- wp-admin-bar-new-content 
ordering ---- li:eq(0)

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      // swaps 3rd and puts it before the 1st menu (note that orders start at 0)
  $("#wp-admin-bar-new-content li:eq(3)").before($("#wp-admin-bar-new-content li:eq(0)"));
});
```

new order would be (post,media,book,page) You would have to change this if new plugins add new menus but it will work for you until you look into the below.

This page from the wordpress https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_nodes  shows how to build a new menu drop down containing all menus in the admin bar and possibly could be edited to recreate the changes via a wordpress hook letting you rebuild the 'new-content' to suit your needs with more control.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the jQuery solution as well. It works, but has two disadvantages.  First, it uses jQuery, which is not the cleanest approach to solving the issue (I was hoping for a PHP only solution). Second, if there are other menu items as you specified, then the order will not be right.